# How to prevent password prompt to programs when doing special jobs?

Tags: sudo, password

Ubuntu Software and many other package managers will ask sudo password only when try to remove or install packages, how to set them not to do so but can still get the jobs done?

Maybe a non-root program calls/runs a root program that makes the password prompted, `visudo` appending 'MYUSERNAME ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/program' not work in this case.

Comment: How do you expect to perform actions that require super-user privileges without asking for a password?

Comment: Welcome to U&L, not sure what you meant, you can ask for password verification using `sudo -v` before running command.

Comment: @KKusa I don't want to run the whole part of program in super-user privilege, like `Ubuntu Software` just need super-user password sometimes.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Installing applications requires root privileges. There are ways around, searching `ubuntu install applications without root privileges` will show many. Allowing installations w/o sudo is unwise, tho', for various reasons.

Comment: What about other program like `gparted` and `gnome disk`?

Comment: @Archemar : Put `sudo` before program will get  whole part of program in super-user privilege??

Comment: Ubuntu Software and GParted are using Polkit for those authentication prompts - you can configure Polkit to not require password authentication for those: https://askubuntu.com/a/614537/158442

Comment: @muru: Thank you, it's what I want when running GUI as normal user.

Comment: What to do this if a non-root command line program when calling root program?

Comment: I don't have access to `man sudo` now. basically, `sudo -v` will ask for for a password and keep, for a certain time, a validation token that will run further `sudo` commands without password.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/614534/disable-authentication-prompts-in-15-04/614537#614537 seems this will doesn't specific the username.